# UISegmentedControl deselect (make none of the segments selected)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, iboutlet

in fact the title contains my question.
I have a UISegmentedControl, and need to deselect currently selected tab.
I tried:

```
[menu setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];
```

menu being the UBOutlet for uisegmentedcontrol but this gives me exception.
anyone have some idea?
thanks
peter

Comment: I'd also suggest using UISegmentedControlNoSegment instead of -1 - it's not a source of problem here but just in case

Comment: 2010-02-05 11:10:16.799 Gazetapl[30839:20b] *** -[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d39ed0

[Session started at 2010-02-05 11:10:16 +0100.]
2010-02-05 11:10:16.800 Gazetapl[30839:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d39ed0'
2010-02-05 11:10:16.802 Gazetapl[30839:20b] Stack: (

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would assume that you've called `[myArray length]` instead of the proper `[myArray count]` somewhere in your code. NSArray uses the count method, not length for the number of items it contains.

Comment: hi, i don't understand. what does this have to do with uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: Nothing directly, but based on the exception you posted, the problem is not with UISegementedControl. Perhaps somewhere in your handling of changing the selected segment you access an array.

Comment: Why the down vote? Mine is the only answer that actually addresses the problem dusker was having.

Comment: Actually, your answer does not address the question. The op wants to deselect a segment from a UISegmentedController.

Comment: The OP asked the wrong question (can be clearly seen by the exception), this is the correct answer. It addresses the problem 100%.

Comment: What a tangent. But I commend your insight.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to have no option selected at all...swift option below show be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 253):

The right way to do this is:

```
[menu setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

Edit:

**Swift 5**:

```
menu.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
```

Comment: I do not understand why OP does not select this answer!.

Comment: @Ali because this wasn't his question. He was already doing this (mostly) correctly. His problem was elsewhere as I explained.

Comment: @DavidKanarek but it really doesn't make sense, this is the answer and I had the same problem, I googled it, this was the first google result, and this is the answer, strange, also in the question I can't see any other code or exceptions..!

Answer (score 32):

Setting the segmentedControl to `.momentary = YES` changes the way the user can interact with the segmentedControl. If you want to have nothing selected initially when the page loads but have segmentedControl behave the same after a selection is made by the user then you will want something more like this:

**Swift 4 solution**:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

 self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
```

**Swift 5.1**:

```
 self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
```

Answer (score 31):

I guess you try to create a momentary selection in segmented control.
In interface builder set the segmentedcontrol to momentary.
Or in code you can do:

```
menu.momentary = YES;
```

Comment: Momentary will still result in a segment being selected on load. Besides, use of Momentary should only be because you actually want a Momentary segment control, not just to try to force no segment selection. Use the UISegmentedControlNoSegment solution.

Answer (score 8):

I did class which supports this kind of interaction:

```
class UIDeselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        if previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {

            self.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
            let touch = touches.first!
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main advantage of that is that you just need to modify which class the Storyboard/Xib/ViewCode is using and this will work like a charm ;]

Answer (score 7):

swift 4

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl! {
    didSet {
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this in xcode 6 in the interface builder:

`Deselect the 'Selected' option under segmented control behaviour in attributes inspector.`

Answer (score 2):

The Swift solution: `@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!` and `mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1`.