# UISegmentControl Selection Empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi When i create Segment control I need to show UISegment control without selection. I tried following code but no luck.

```
[_userSeg setSelectedSegmentIndex:nil];
```

and

```
[_userSeg setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISegmentedControl deselect (make none of the segments selected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206066/uisegmentedcontrol-deselect-make-none-of-the-segments-selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Check below code Hope It works.

Objective C:

```
[_userSeg setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

Swift:

```
userSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(UISegmentedControlNoSegment)
```

Comment: just for extra information you can replace 
        Int(UISegmentedControlNoSegment) with -1; 
that would do the trick.